# variable _GET [array] en PHP me sale indefinida, como lo soluciono?

Tags: php, get

estoy haciendo un switch para recoger el valor con _GET pero me da error de variable indefinida.

he probado ponerlo en switch

```
switch ($_GET["disco"]){
```

he probado con un if

```
if (!empty($disco)) {
    echo "<h1>Bienvenido</h1>";
} else {
    $disco = $_GET["disco"];
}
```

e probado mas cosas pero no resulta nada
me pueden hecha una manita por favor??

```
    if (isset($_GET['disco'])) {
    $disco1 = $_GET["disco"];
}


switch ($disco1) {
    case "1":
        $nombre = "Anuel AA";
        $disco = "Las Leyendas Nunca Mueren";
        $year = "2021";
        $portada = "lasleyendas";
        $obj1 = new Artistas($nombre, $disco, $year, $portada);
        break;

    case "2":
        $nombre = "Anuel AA";
        $disco = "Los Dioses";
        $year = "2020";
        $portada = "losdioses";
        $obj1 = new Artistas($nombre, $disco, $year, $portada);
        break;


}
```

Comment: Y que estas mandando por el url?

Comment: encierra el switch dentro del if

Comment: muchas gracias @masterguru funciono!!